# How to Display Partial File Name of an uploaded file in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html I have an input element where the user can upload a file. The name of the uploaded file gets displayed next to it. When the name has a certain length, only the first x letters should be displayed so there ist no line break. But when one hovers over the partly displayed name, it should show the whole name.

```
<form id="formId">
        <label for="inputId">Upload file</label>
        <input type="file" id="inputId" accept=".json,.manifest">
</form>
```

My idea was to make input element hidden and create another button that clicks it so a file can be uploaded. I would take the name of the file through the id of the inputfield.value and than shorten it, so it can be display in a paragraph below. Is there a better/easier solution for this problem?

Comment: _"and create another button that clicks it"_ - you don't need to add a button, clicking the label will already trigger the file upload dialog.

Comment: As for the partial file name have a look at [text-overflow: ellipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: I know that but it´s not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `text-overflow: ellipsis;` will work if the container is sized with an absolute value.  This became a big enough issue for me that I've resorted to javascript solutions in the past.

Here's an implementation that should work:

```js
const FILE_NAME_CONTAINER_ELEMENT = document.querySelector('file-name-span') || document.createElement('span'); /* Replace with your file name element */
const FILE_PICKER_INPUT = document.getElementById("inputId") || document.createElement('input');
const ELLIPSIS_STRING = '...'; /* Allows you to change to a single character ellipsis if needed */
const FILE_NAME_STRING_MAX_LENGTH = 16; /* Replace with the max length the file name should be BEFORE the ellipsis */

FILE_PICKER_INPUT.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    console.log('dd')
  const files = event.target.files;
  const fileCount = files.length;
  if (fileCount === 0) {
    FILE_NAME_CONTAINER_ELEMENT.innerText = '';
    return FILE_NAME_CONTAINER_ELEMENT.title = '';
  }
  const filenameArray = [];
  // Using a loop to account for multiple files
  for (let index = 0; index < fileCount; index++) {
    filenameArray.push(files[index].name);
  }
  let string = filenameArray.join(', ');
  FILE_NAME_CONTAINER_ELEMENT.title = string;
  if (string.length > FILE_NAME_STRING_MAX_LENGTH) {
    string = string.substring(0, FILE_NAME_STRING_MAX_LENGTH) + ELLIPSIS_STRING;
  }
    console.log(string)
  FILE_NAME_CONTAINER_ELEMENT.innerText = string;
});
```

Take note that if you need to rely on the actual width of an element that this will have to be reworked to calculate the computed value of the element and compare it to the width of the file name when rendered.  Followed by looping through different lengths to find the one that fits.